# Android studio: Is there a way to make the code for the default nav bar work?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have downloaded the newsest version of android studio which is Android studio 3.0.1 I have created a project and selected the 'Bottom navigation activity'. I have created two other XML layouts and also two other java activities. I have no idea as to how to link these screens to the navigation bar. Does anybody know how i do this? like a step by step thing. This isn't one of my strongest subjects lol and i also have been online but cant find the right information.

Comment: You should make a fragment for each tab of your bottom navigation view then respond to clicks by changing each fragment in a container possibly a `FrameLayout`.

Comment: Thank you will give this a try tonight :)